# bash command outputs 'No such file or directory'

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, macos-high-sierra

I have to follow instructions for a Java project but know nothing about Terminal.

I basically created what seems to be a path by typing `cd /'path'` which leads to a folder.
In this folder is located a file I need to execute a bash command on `bash updatemcp.sh`.

The file only contains:

`#!/bin/bash
./runtime/updatemcp.py "$@"`

When I run it with the dot at the beginning of the path it outputs this: `env: python2: No such file or directory`

However whenever I execute the command without the dot at the beginning of the second line of the file it outputs this: `updatemcp.sh: line 2: /runtime/updatemcp.py: No such file or directory` when I'm 100% sure there is a file called updatemcp.py here...

The runtime folder is in the folder is contained in the `dc 'path'` folder

Thanks in advance

Comment: Install Python v2.x

Comment: Hi. I would suggest you'll first make yourself familiar with the terminal a little https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/command-line-basics-and-useful-tricks-with-the-terminal--cms-29356
Regarding your script, it looks like python (specifically python2) is required for your script but not installed (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/)

Comment: `env: python2: No such file or directory` means `updatemcp.py` starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python2`. That means that an executable named `python2` needs to be present in your PATH, ie. that `which python2` or `type -P python2` be able to find the location of same.

Comment: BTW, unrelated to your problem, but it would be ever so slightly more efficient to change the 2nd line to `exec ./runtime/updatemcp.py "$@"` -- that tells the shell script it can stop executing immediately and let the program it's invoking take over its process table entry. Of course, you can only do this safely when it's the very last command your shell script is expected to execute.

Comment: @thatotherguy I do have it as when I type `python` in Terminal it outputs the version

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't quite get your answer, which parts of the files do I need to edit then?

Comment: @Miloertas, but you aren't trying to run `python`, you're trying to run `python2`. What does it do when you type `python2` into the Terminal? If it says it's not found, (1) there's your problem; (2) you can fix it by either *creating* a `python2` link in the PATH (like the flagged duplicate tells you to), or by fixing the shebang that's the first line of `updatemcp.py` to refer to the Python executable under a name it's actually installed with.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think that's the issue, Though I didn't quite understood what I needed to do in order to fix that problem

Comment: Easy answer: Open your script in a text editor, and change `python2` in the very first line to `python`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, but the first line of my file is #!/bin/bash and not python

Comment: Open the *Python* script (`updatemcp.py`) and change that line.

Comment: It's a shell script, and when I do that it won't work, I don't want to waste your time really I do feel like my case is hopeless

Comment: `updatemcp.py` (not `.sh`, but the `.py` file it calls) is a shell script? It's a rather grossly misnamed one, if so.

Comment: ...anyhow, a fallback approach is to change `./runtime/updatemcp.py "$@"` to `python ./runtime/updatemcp.py "$@"`